# Axios Delete - Type 'UserModelDelete' has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

How to solve this problem? Axios Delete -  Type 'UserModelDelete' has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig'

I don't understand how to solve this problem.
[Axios problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2wZy.png)

[axios call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSjai.png)

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZqGf.png)

I try to Delete vacation from mySql DB but have problem with Axios, I don't understand how solve this problem.

Comment: Please make sure to post raw code and not pictures of your code, it's way easier for us to copy / paste in our production environement in order to test the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [Axios' documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios). The second parameter of the `delete` function expects a config object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're passing a wrong parameter to axios.delete().

An example call would be:

```
axios.delete(url, { data: { user: "name" }, headers: { "Authorization": "token" } });
```

So you can try:

```
axios.delete(url, { data: userDataDelete });
```

You can check the [Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) for more info